# How can I input @ to send mails, when my keyboard layout requires pressing Alt?

Tags: pc, neverwinter

If I want to send a mail to someone, I have to enter the character's name like this: `char_name@player_account` or the player's account name like this: `@player_account`

However, whenever I try to enter the `@` char, the mail interface disappears as a result of pressing the **Alt** key on my keyboard. In my case, the `@` char requires pressing **Ctrl + Alt + 2** simultaneously (alternatively **AltGr + 2**).

How can I work around that issue, preferrably without copy-paste and without changing my keyboard layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to enter the `@` char, you'll need to press all keys required at the same time.

That is; instead of pressing first **AltGr** then pressing **2** while **AltGr** is down, you have to press both keys **at the same time** (as far as humanly possible).

Of course, the mail interface will disappear as a result of pressing the **Alt** key, but as soon as you interact with the *Postal Courrier* again, the `@` char will sit safe and sound within the address text box.

Writing mail like this might be bothersome, but it's definitely less bothersome than having to copy-paste `@` from another window or changing one's keyboard layout.
All that's left to do, is hoping for *Cryptic* to notice that not all players have American layout keyboards and fix that annoying design bug accordingly.

## Edit:

I just noticed, this may be a bug in Neverwinter. According to the default keybindings, *Toggle cursor mode* is bound to **Left Alt**, and not to **Alt** in general. Doesn't make it less annoying...

Alternatively, binding the *Toggle cursor mode* to a different key may do the trick. Just tested it with **Ctrl** and it works perfectly with the **AltGr + 2** combo. Thanks @Viper_Sb

Comment: You can also reset your release mouse key to something other then Alt, just go to the key bindings in the options.

Comment: @Viper_Sb True, I can't believe I hadn't thought about that. Stupid me...